# Is there a replacement for comment driven?

Tags: 7, comments

The comment driven module and similarly the comment alter module are dead or dieing and have no ports to drupal 7. Anyone know if there is a module that could replace either of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a replacement for my uses of comment driven. Its called [Node Changes](http://drupal.org/project/nodechanges), and allows changes to nodes to be recorded as comments.

> This module stores the changes of a node into a field attached to comments allowing to display a kind-of activity stream on the node much like on drupal.org issues just with a lot less custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Comment Alter](https://drupal.org/project/comment_alter) 
Module which makes it possible to alter (change values of) fields on a node when leaving a comment.
However, unlike those modules which have the available fields hard-coded, this module allows you to edit any field on a content type and check "Enable altering this field from comments"!

> This can be used to create a tracker similar to Case Tracker or other support or project management modules.